# View Size for YTPlayer

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the iOS YouTube Player helper (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) and it works just fine but the preview image is not the size of my view and I can't figure out how to change it so it fits within the UIView I've created. How can I make it fill the view?

Here is what it looks like.
[image]

Comment: did you ever get this fixed? im trying to fix this exact problem but not having any luck so far...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This solved it for me:

In the Assets folder there should be an html file named "YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html"

Replace the existing code between "style" tags as shown below and this will make sure the Player fills 100% of the YTPlayerView:

```
<style>
    body { margin: 0; width:100%%; height:100%%; }
    html { width:100%%; height:100%%; }
</style>
```

Hope this helps a bit! Have a great weekend!

Comment: Aargh ... why on earth is this not solved right in the library? When it's included as a pod changing the asset is a really ugly hack that breaks with each pod update ...

Comment: ive tried what youve said, but editing those values doesnt change the size for some reason. would you submit sample code please @AppsIntheParkNYC? thank you !

Comment: Not updating as per the answer.

Comment: This is the default style in more recent versions and results in a video that is 100% height and a proportional width (in portrait). This means you will have a video significantly wider than the width of the the device, but cropped.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset webView size in the following method:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //
   self.player.webView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.player.bounds.size.width, self.player.bounds.size.height*1.5);

    [self.player.webView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find another solution.
If you use YTPlayerView in a xib file, please make sure the following points.

1, Check 'Use Auto Layout'

2, DO NOT set the width and height value for YTPlayerView.

then the YTPlayerView will play normally.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but since none of the other solutions worked for me, I solved it by constraining the webView / YTPlayerView to a 16:9 aspect ratio as that is the standard aspect ratio for YouTube videos according to this:

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6375112?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

With your webView/playerView the same aspect ratio as the video, the preview image will display properly.