# Unable to control the display size of a YTPlayerView instance in a storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, youtube-api

No matter how I size my `YTPlayerView` instance in my storyboard the resulting view (when run on the simulator) is always half the height of what I set in the storyboard. Auto Layout and Size Classes are disabled for this view controller.

I'm using the latest version of [youtube-ios-player-helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) from Google and Xcode 6.3.1.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Check this answer [View Size for YTPlayer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24819532/1426973)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using CocoaPods I manually added `YTPlayerView` to my project (the procedure is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper#installation_manual)) and everything worked as expected.

Comment: Just for reference, the YouTube devs haven't updated the pod so if you install the library via Cocoapods you will be installing an old version.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure but I think thats the way it works, I tried to change the dimensions of the `YouTubePlayerView` on Android, it also does not follow the dimensions, it tries to fit the screen.

But I am pretty sure that Youtube player framework for JavaScript `iframe` is more flexible than platform specific frameworks. Its very easy and simple, [click here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) if you want to have a look at it.