# iframe on IOS cropping webview

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I am trying to embed a youtube video using the YTPlayerView so set its frame and load the content but the video is being cropped:

[image]

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
                             @"controls" : @0,
                             @"playsinline" : @1,
                             @"autohide" : @1,
                             @"showinfo" : @0,
                             @"modestbranding" : @1
                             };
    [self.view addSubview:self.playerView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.slider];
    [self.view addSubview:self.playButton];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.playerView.delegate = self;
    [self.playerView loadWithVideoId:self.videoId playerVars:playerVars];
}

-(YTPlayerView *)playerView{
    if (!_playerView) {
        _playerView = [[YTPlayerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 84,      self.view.frame.size.width - 10, 250)];
    }
    return _playerView;
}
```

Any way of filling the view properly?

Comment: Have you tried changing the styling as suggested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24819532/4241842) answer?

Comment: the default YTPlayerView-.html already has these values in the <head> tags

Answer (score 1):

_playerView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Put It After Creating Object of YTPlayerView.May be Its Works.